# Issue Binding Events to SoundCloud Widget

Tags: javascript, html, widget, soundcloud, audio-player

I'm binding finish event to the widget and it works fine for the first widget, but not the second one on the same page.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null

This is how I'm initializing it.

```
var widget = SC.Widget($instance[0]);
widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, function(){
    options.done();
});
```

The use case is to display 1 track at a time. When the first one is done, the second one is loaded. Because of this exception, I'm not able to play second one. I understand I can use the SDK to do this, but I'm trying to use the widget so I don't have to come up with my own UI.

Any idea? This is clearly a bug on SoundCloud Widget API. I'm trying to see if there is a workaround.

---

**EDITED**

Updated to include some more info. This is a very simple case and there isn't anything special about it.

Simplified JS - This is pretty much it for Javascript. There is nothing special about it.

```
var $track1 = $('<iframe id="sc1" src="//w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/79973942&amp;hide_related=true&amp;visual=true&amp;auto_play=true" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
$('body').append($track1);
var widget = SC.Widget($track1[0]);
widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, function(){
    $track1.remove();
    var $track2 = $('<iframe id="sc2" src="//w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/131713700&amp;hide_related=true&amp;visual=true&amp;auto_play=true" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
    $('body').append($track2);
    var widget = SC.Widget($track2[0]);
    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, function(){
        console.log('Done');
    });
});
```

---

**EDITED 2**

Forgot to mention that these frames are added dynamically. I have adjusted the code to match.

Comment: hey, can you please show the whole code? here you are only interacting with one widget in your code example, so it's hard to tell what doesn't work exactly, thanks!

Comment: This is pretty much the whole thing. Will edit to also include HTML.

Comment: Your example works as expected: http://jsbin.com/xeyede/1 (go here to see the code http://jsbin.com/xeyede/1/edit)

Comment: It actually doesn't. Maybe I missed out 1 detail. The iframe gets appended dynamically into the page and it's automatically played. Your example removed the "auto_play" param and maybe that could work as a workaround. I will try that out later. My use case can include 100s of tracks so all widgets are appended dynamically.

Comment: Dynamically creating the widget – http://jsbin.com/xeyede/2

Comment: I found a workaround for my case. If put the initialization of the subsequent track into a different context (setTimeout = 1), it works consistently. I have no idea why, but I have seen similar issue with Google Maps before also. I have a lot of timeout that is used to manage the state of my playlist and I'm thinking it's something to do with that. All tracks are added after certain interval. Will post more update if I can figure out the actual reason why it doesn't just work without this workaround.